# Trigger execution of a AWS lambda function at a specific time depending on code logic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have a question related to AWS on how to trigger a Lambda function based on time.
I have a booking system where users can book a ride. I want to send an automated notification for them e.g. 10 mins from the time rider should arrive in case the rider is late.
How can I trigger the lambda function to run (as an example 02:30 and the current time is 12:00)

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you could have hundreds of users who need to receive notifications at any particular time. Therefore, merely triggering the Lambda function at a particular time probably isn't the way to accomplish this.

Instead, you could:

- Use a database to maintain the times that users should be notified
- Trigger an AWS Lambda function every minute
- The Lambda function would:

  - Consult the database to find any notification that is due to be sent now (or previously) and has not already been sent
  - Send the notification
  - Mark the notification as sent (or delete it from the database)

Note that the function should look for *any* notification that is due, even if it was for a previous time. This will handle situations where notifications were not successfully sent previously, or where the Lambda function doesn't run for some reason.

The Lambda function can be triggered on a schedule by using Amazon CloudWatch Events.